# Why is this an invalid use of Scala's abstract types?

Tags: scala, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract-type

I have this code:

```
class A extends Testable { type Self <: A }

class B extends A { type Self <: B }

trait Testable {
    type Self
    def test[T <: Self] = {}
}

object Main {
    val h = new A
    // this throws an error
    h.test[B]
}
```

And my error is:

```
error: type arguments [B] do not conform to method test's type parameter bounds [T <: Main.h.Self]
    h.test[B]
```

On [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25002651/scala-abstract-types-in-classes-within-objects/25003850#25003850) question, it was said that this was due to path dependent types. Can anyone figure out how to have T <: Self, without having the path-dependent types problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code need to be looks like:

```
// --- fictional scala syntax ---
class A extends Testable { type Self = A }
class B extends A { override type Self = B }
```

But it is **imposible** in current version of scala.

I would propose little bit long way (not longer than using path dependent types but another), and it conforms your requirements.

a) Use Type-class pattern for test method;

b) Use implicit parameters for conforms type relations.

Class hierarchy:

```
trait Testable
class A extends Testable
class B extends A
```

Conforms trait:

```
trait Conforms[X, Y]
```

Testable Type-class:

```
object TestableTypeClass {
  implicit def testMethod[T <: Testable](testable : T) = new {
    def test[X](implicit ev : Conforms[X, T]) = {}
  }
}
```

`test` method type parameter conditions in companion objects:

```
object A {
  // P <: A is your conditon (Self <: A) for class A
  implicit def r[P <: A] = new Conforms[P , A] {}
}
object B {
  // P <: B is your conditon (Self <: B) for class B
  implicit def r[P <: B] = new Conforms[P , B] {}
}
```

Tests:

```
import TestableTypeClass._

val a = new A
a.test[A]    // - Ok
a.test[B]    // - Ok

val b = new B
// b.test[A] // - did not compile
b.test[B]    // - Ok
```

**UPDATE:**

1) It is possible to collect all implicits in one object, and in this case object with implicits need to import (it is not needed before by rules of implicit scope in companion object):

```
object ImplicitContainer {
  implicit def r1[P <: A] = new Conforms[P , A] {}
  implicit def r2[P <: B] = new Conforms[P , B] {}
}
```

and using:

```
import TestableTypeClass._
import ImplicitContainer._

val a = new A
a.test[A]
a.test[B]
```

2,3) trait `Conforms` defined for 2 type parameter `X` & `Y`

X - used for future type constraint (and this constraint come from parametric method)

Y - used for determine the type for which will be define type constraint

implicit parameter choise by `Comforms` instance type, and idea of this design is playing with combinations X & Y

in Type-class `TestableTypeClass` type Y captured by implicit conversion from `Testable` to anonimous class with `test` method, and type X captured in `test` method call.

And a main feature is invariance of `Conforms` trait, this is why implicits is not ambiguous and correctly manage bound rules.

And for better understanding, one more example with more strict rules:

```
//...
class C extends B

object ImplicitContainer {
  implicit def r1[P <: A] = new Conforms[P , A] {}
  implicit def r2[P](implicit ev : P =:= B) = new Conforms[P , B] {}
  implicit def r3[P <: C] = new Conforms[P , C] {}
}


import TestableTypeClass._
import ImplicitContainer._

val b = new B
//b.test[A]    // - did not compile
b.test[B]      // - Ok
//b.test[C]    // - did not compile
```

Comment: I was kind of trying to avoid implicits, but this looks good, only one implicit per class I suppose. Question: Do I have to put each implicit in the classes' respective companion objects, or can I just put them all in one object?

Comment: And just a question on how this works, when looking for the implicit parameter ev, does it look in the companion object for a function that produces a suitable type? Seems like double implicit

Comment: And finally, do the r functions have to be def's because you can't have generic type restrictions with a val?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to achieve is something like this:

```
//this is of course not a correct Scala code
def test[T <: upperBoundOf[Self]]
```

But this doesn't make sense. Why? Because you can very easily circumvent such constraint, effectively rendering it pointless:

```
val h = new B
h.test[A] //nope, A is not a subtype of B
```

but...

```
val h: A = new B
h.test[A] //same thing, but this time it's apparently OK
```

Not only the constraint provides zero additional type safety, I think it also leads to breakage one of the most fundamental rules of OOP - the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). The snippet above compiles when `h` is of type `A` but does not compile when `h` is of type `B` even though it's a subtype of `A`, so everything should be fine according to the LSP.

So, essentially if you just leave your types like this:

```
class A extends Testable
class B extends A
trait Testable {
  def test[T <: A]
}
```

you have exactly the same level of type safety.

Comment: I know what I'm doing with breaking the OOP principle, but that's useful info for future readers. However, your second code snippet is wrong. h.test[A] would NOT work in my hypothetical code, because A is not a subtype of B. It doesn't matter what static type you gave h, because type Self = B when you say new B. Get what I mean?

Comment: @mdenton8 I guess you need to specify in detail what rules are you exactly trying to enforce using Scala type system. If `T <: upperBoundOf[Self]` is not what you want, then what is it?

Comment: T <: Self is what I want... When I say new B, then type Self = B. Then, B <: Self, but A is NOT <: Self.

Comment: And with class C extends B, C <: Self

Comment: I know I'm essentially trying to beat dynamic types. This only needs to be done in one location. Can I use generics to beat this, maybe?

Comment: @mdenton8 "When I say `new B` then `type Self = B`" - Scala can't do that which I mentioned in one of your previous questions. When you write `val h = new B` then type inference will assign type `B` to identifier `h`. So the compiler will remember that `h` is of type `B` **including subtypes of B**. It will not track the information that `h` is **exactly B** despite the fact that a constructor was involved.

Comment: Right, but the point of my code was to get type Self = B, whether I actually use that syntax or not.